# How To send mass mailer with PHPMailer Library

Tags: php

How to send mass mailer? the error info is "You must provide at least one recipient email address." This my code

```
$recipient_list = 'recipient1@gmail.com, recipient2@gmail.com';    
$sender_list = 'sender1@gmail.com, sender2@gmail.com';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Testing';    
$mail->Body    = 'normal <br> <b>bold';

$recipient_address = explode(", ", $recipient_list);

$sender_array = explode(", ", $sender_list);

$sender_address = $sender_array[array_rand($sender_array)];

for($x = 0; $x < count($recipient_address); $x++) {

$mail->setFrom('$sender_address');

$mail->AddCC = '$recipient_list[$x]';

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "<title>Maill Error</title><center><font size='20' color='20'></center></font><br><br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo . " ";
    } else {
        echo "<title>Maill Success</title><center><font size='20' color='green'>Success</center></font><br><br>" . $sender_address . " sending to " . $recipient_list . "<br><br>";
        }
 $mail->clearAddresses();    
 }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Is this a typo mistake?

Comment: you dont specify an email body or any recipients, have a look at the requirements for PHPMailer

Comment: sorry i forget that, but the the error is same :'(

Comment: please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a primary recipient.

`$mail->addAddress($recipient);`

This is needed because you cannot send an email only to "CC"'s